# Node novice - purpose of require('express')

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

In the following simple socketIo server, can any node ninja explain the purpose of the very first line. I'm not using express to actually create the server which is http based so would it work just as well without?
A bit confused...

```
var app = require('express')();
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);


server.listen(8080);

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.sendfile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.on('connection', function (socket) {

  console.log('connection '+socket);
    socket.on("data",function(d){console.log('data from flash: ',d);});
  socket.emit("message","hello from server");
  socket.emit('news', { hello: 'world' });
  socket.on('disconnect', function (data) {
    console.log(' disconnect');
  });
});
```

Comment: Where would `app` come from if you removed that line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line:

```
var app = require('express')();
```

loads the `express` module (that's what `require(...)` does) and then calls its constructor to initialize it and then assigns the result into a variable named `app`.  The `app` variable is then used by your code in a couple other places.

These steps are required in order to use the `express` module.

Note how your code is then passing the `app` (created by Express) to your http server.  This hooks express into your http server as a request listener so that it can offer its routing features which you are then using with `app.get(...)`.

If you remove that first line, your code will not work at all.

You could create a vanilla HTTP server without using Express, but then you'd have to write your own requestListeners and could not use the many other routing and middleware features of Express.

Comment: thanks for a great answer. So express in my case is being used for the request listeners and routing

Comment: @eco_bach - yes, that is correct.  It plugs into the HTTP server to provide an easier framework for handling web requests.  Your `app.get()` and `res.sendFile()` are both functionality provided by Express.  If you get further into designing a web app, Express will help with many other aspects of a web app too (cookies, JSON, integrating with template engines, all sorts of third party middleware, etc....